# Excel VBA - copying cell contents from one sheet to another

Tags: vba, excel

I am working on a project where a large amount of data is stored in an excel workbook, with a new sheet for every quarter.  I need need to create a dashboard of the data which shows graphs of data from the last 4 quarters.  I have set a dropdown to select the quarter and am attempting to pull the relevant data through from the source sheets to the dashboard sheet but I just can't get it to work.

```
    Private Sub SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim Q4 As Integer, Q1 As Integer, Q2 As Integer, Q3 As Integer, selectedQ As Variant


    'read selected quarter
    selectedQ = ActiveSheet.Range("B3").Value


        'compare selected quarter to identify sheet index
        'Q4 is current quarter

        If selectedQ = "15-16 Q4" Then Q4 = 10 Else
            If selectedQ = "16-17 Q1" Then Q4 = 11 Else
            If selectedQ = "16-17 Q2" Then Q4 = 12 Else
            If selectedQ = "16-17 Q3" Then Q4 = 13 Else
            If selectedQ = "16-17 Q4" Then Q4 = 14 Else
            If selectedQ = "17-18 Q1" Then Q4 = 15 Else
            If selectedQ = "17-18 Q2" Then Q4 = 16 Else
            If selectedQ = "17-18 Q3" Then Q4 = 17 Else
            If selectedQ = "17-18 Q4" Then Q4 = 18 Else
            If selectedQ = "18-19 Q1" Then Q4 = 19 Else
        End If

        'set sheet index for previous quarters
        If Q4 > 3 Then
            Q3 = Q4 - 1
            Q2 = Q4 - 2
            Q1 = Q4 - 3
        End If


        'fill current quarter using Sheets(1).Range(1, 1) as source

            'under 3 reg
            ActiveSheet.Range("C10").Value = Sheets(Q4).Range("Z21").Value
            ActiveSheet.Range("C11").Value = Sheets(Q4).Range("Z29").Value
            ActiveSheet.Range("C12").Value = Sheets(Q4).Range("Z39").Value
            ActiveSheet.Range("C13").Value = Sheets(Q4).Range("Z50").Value
            ActiveSheet.Range("C14:C19").Value = Sheets(Q4).Range("Z60:Z65").Value



End Sub
```

I initially started this project on a mac but have also tried to debug this on windows office 2007.  When I watch the variable *selectedQ* on the PC it shows the message "can't compile module".  What am I missing?

Thanks in advance

Iain

Comment: I should have added that the Q1 - Q4 is to select data from 4 different sheets.  Debugging this however shows that the code isn't picking up selectedQ from the sheet to then identify the other sheets to retrieve the cell contents from.

Comment: be sure that `ActiveSheet` is the one whose cell "B3" you have to pick value from. you'd better use some fully qualified name like `Worksheets("MySheet").Range("B3")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you could simply go like follows:

```
Q4 = 6 + (Left(selectedQ, 2) - 15)*4 + Right(selectedQ, 1)
```

Should you want to keep it like you're doing then you'd better use a `Select Case` construct like follows:

```
Select Case 
    Case "15-16 Q4"
          Q4 = 10
    Case "16-17 Q1"
          Q4 = 11
    Case "16-17 Q2"
          Q4 = 12
    Case "16-17 Q3"
          Q4 = 13
    Case "16-17 Q4"
          Q4 = 14
    Case "17-18 Q1"
          Q4 = 15
    Case "17-18 Q2"
          Q4 = 16
    Case "17-18 Q3"
          Q4 = 17
    Case "17-18 Q4"
          Q4 = 18
    Case "18-19 Q1"
          Q4 = 19
End Select
```

Comment: Thanks.  I will try this.

Answer (score 0):

Your If statement should be

```
If selectedQ = "15-16 Q4" Then 
    Q4 = 10
ElseIf selectedQ = "16-17 Q1" Then 
    Q4 = 11 
ElseIf selectedQ = "16-17 Q2" Then 
    Q4 = 12
ElseIf selectedQ = "16-17 Q3" Then
' Etc
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that you chosen to use the index of the sheets, Sheets(Q4) where Q4 is integer, this may cause errors if someone added, moved, or removed sheets from the workbook.

I highly recommend you to use the names of the worksheets instead. the formula will be Sheets("Sheet's name").value
You can construct a simple function that loops over names to get the previous sheets' names for Q3, Q3, and Q1 if you want. In all ways, I advice you to limit the errors chance of using sheet indices.

---

Another notice, that I advice you to use the formal If, Then, Else if,  , , Else, End if. Not the nested If you used, otherwise use the select Case statement that suggested by @user3598756.

Best Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestions above, especially the select case.

In the end I believe the problem was caused by a corruption that occurred due to using a file from an older version of office, then working on it in a newer office version and on office for Mac.  I was really starting to doubt myself, but copying and pasting everything into a blank workbook solved the problem.